# Interceptor in Win32 legacy application

Tags: .net, winapi, aop

In C# we use Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor to intercept method calls for logging purposes, we are interested in the arguments and return value, eg:

```
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Debug(invocation.Method.DeclaringType.Name + "." + invocation.Method.Name + "(" + string.Join(", ", invocation.Arguments.Select(a => (GetValue(a) ?? "").ToString()).ToArray()) + ")");
        invocation.Proceed();

        string returnValue = GetValue(invocation.ReturnValue);

        Debug($"{invocation.Method.DeclaringType.Name}.{invocation.Method.Name}.Result: {returnValue}");
    }
```

We have a Win32 application that we would like to do something similar for. Is this at all possible without having to put tracing statements in every single method? Is there a way to intercept method calls like in .net in Win32? The language is called Visual Objects.

Thank you

Comment: That depends on your ability to instruct the compiler to emit required metadata, as well as your ability to tap into the language runtime's inner workings. I'm not familiar with Visual Objects, so I cannot comment on that in particular.

Comment: This isn't a winapi question. Any possible solution will be specific to the language and its associated tooling. Please tag the question accordingly.